# Laravel relationship DB connection

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I m trying to get Model relationship with different connection, basically my connections are dynamic.

```
$con = 'con1'
$persons = new \App\Models\Person;
$persons->setConnection($con);
$persons = $persons->where('somevalue', 1)->get()
```

So here I get Person from con1 (where con1 is stored in config/databse.php
It can be con2, con3, con4 and etc.

However this works, but when I am trying to loop through this data and get relationship it switches to default Database connection.

```
@foreach($persons as $person)
   {{$person->data->name}}
@endforeach
```

In above loop `data` is a belongsTo relation ship in Person Model, and it throws error because it switches back to default Database connection and not using con1

`It is possible to setConnection() and keep for hasMany relationship and also for belongsTo relationship?`

**I cant set `protected $connection;` in Model because connections are changble**

What I tried until now is I created an absctract class that extendseloquent, and my models extending this abstract class

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

abstract class Database extends Eloquent {
    protected $connection;
}
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use App\Models\Database as Database;
class Person extends Database{
    protected $table = 'persons';
}
```

So theoritically when I `setConnection` I set connection to all models that extends this `class` but still no luck.

Comment: It can't be done because it's trying to join these tables.  There is no way to join tables on different connections.

Comment: @user3158900 Laravel relationships don't use joins. Theoretically this is possible, but whether the code allows it still needs some research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution maybe wrong but is working:
I create a file in config where I add all my connections:

```
<?php
return [
    'con1' => [
        'name' => 'Persons Connection',
        'url'  => 'persons',
        'active' = true

    ],
    'con2' => [
        'name' => 'Italy Persons Connection',
        'url'  => 'italypersons',
        'active' = false

    ],
];
```

So like this I can event control if con2 is available

In Database connection config file I have `con1` connection with all db data
After in `routes.php` a bind the url example `/info/{con}` `where con = 'persons'`

```
Route::bind('con', function($con, $route){
        foreach(config('connections') as $key => $value){
            if($value['url'] == $con && $value['active'] == true){
                session(['connection' => $key]); //where $key == con1
                return $key;

            }
            abort(404);      
        }
    });
```

So: I have a Class Person that extends abstract method with __construct function

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use App\Models\Database as Database;
class Person extends Eloquent{
    protected $table = 'persons';
}

<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
abstract class Database extends Eloquent {

    function __construct(array $attributes = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        $this->setConnection(session('connection'));
    }
}
```

So like this I am sure if user get to URL `/info/{con}` It will set the connection sessions if it exist in my connections config file, without losing sensitive data from `config/database.php`

If somebody have better idea please write it

Answer (score 1):

You may try `eager loading` of the relationship:

```
$persons = $persons->with('data')->where('somevalue', 1)->get();
```

Comment: I would think that this works. If it doesn't, there's nothing else I can think of. Froxz should give this a try. I have a feeling it might still run the eager load query on the default connection.

Comment: This doesn't work for me when using different connections in relationships. The `with()` method assumes the same connection for both `Person` and `Data`.